# filtered lookup Error in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am using On-Premise crm dynamics 2011 and I am facing problem in the following situation. In Lookup field based on system roles 'system administration' want to  see all options and remaining user want to display required options.Please check this code

```js
function preFilterLookup() 
{
  var viewId="{203CEC53-AFA2-E711-855D-0050568A00CA}";
  var entityName="mmm_escalationactionowner"; 
  var viewName="Escalation Action Owner Filtered"; 
  var filterXML="<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"
              + "<entity name='new_escalationactionowner'>"
              +    "<attribute name='new_escalationactionownerid' />"
              +    "<attribute name='new_name' />"
              +    "<attribute name='createdon' />"
              +    "<order attribute='new_name' descending='false' />"
              +    "<filter type='and'>"
              +      "<filter type='or'>"
              +        "<condition attribute='new_name' operator='eq' value='CBC' />"
              +        "<condition attribute='new_name' operator='eq' value='AMT' />"
              +      "</filter>"
              +    "</filter>"
              +  "</entity>"
              +"</fetch>";
  var layoutXML="<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='name' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'>"
               +"<row name='result'>"
               +"<cell name='name' width='100'/></row></grid>";
}
```

Getting Error while opening the lookup:
[image]

Comment: You may want to check this article: https://crmtipoftheday.com/747/if-your-view-is-broken/. And, while this is unlikely to be the problem, please note that in the FetchXML the `<filter type='and'>` node is unnecessary.

Comment: If i remove "<filter type='and'>" showing an Error "Invalid XML(The XML passed to the platform is not well-formatted XML)"

Comment: Please post all the code of that function

Comment: @Raj, did you also remove the closing `</filter>` tag? I tested a straight "or" filter, and it worked OK `<fetch >
  <entity name='account'>
      <filter type='or'>
        <condition attribute='name' operator='eq' value='CBC' />
        <condition attribute='name' operator='eq' value='AMT' />
      </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>`

Comment: Test it in fetchxml tester first

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
  var layoutXML="<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='name' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'>"
               +"<row name='result'>"
               +"<cell name='name' width='100'/></row></grid>";
```

to following:

```
  var layoutXML="<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='new_name' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'>"
               +"<row name='result'>"
               +"<cell name='new_name' width='100'/></row></grid>";
```

I believe you don't have column with schema name 'name'.